# To run two different tests on sheet names dependant on different variables

Tags: excel, vba

I have individual weekly sheets for staff duties with some sheets I don't want to go public.

I want to publish weekly duty sheets in order onto another multi-week spreadsheet using a macro.

I also want to be able to update these sheets as I make alterations on the private workbook, to delete redundant sheets from this public workbook and to protect it once finished.

Below is what I have so far, I've tried variations, but the macro needs to take different actions depending on whether that weeks sheets are already there and if there are redundant sheets.
I can get some combinations to work but not all.

What steps or commands am I missing or do I need a different approach?

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    'To set variables
    Dim sht As Worksheet
    
    'Current dated sheet
    Dim sname As String
    sname = Sheets("Calc").Range("C18")
    
    'Prior dated sheet
    Dim pname As String
    pname = Sheets("Calc").Range("G18")
    
    'Redundant dated sheet
    Dim delname As String
    delname = Sheets("Calc").Range("C33")
    
        
        'To copy over sheet to Duty Sheets workbook
        'To check if dated sheet exists
        For Each sht In Workbooks("SCL Duties.xlsm").Worksheets
            If sht.Name = sname Then
                'Replace existing sheet with new one
                Application.DisplayAlerts = False
                Workbooks("SCL Duties").Sheets(sname).Delete
                Application.DisplayAlerts = True
                ThisWorkbook.Sheets(sname).Copy After:=Workbooks("SCL Duties.xlsm").Sheets(pname)
    
            End If
    
            'To check for redundant sheet and delete
            If sht.Name = delname Then
                Application.DisplayAlerts = False
                Workbooks("SCL Duties").Sheets(delname).Delete
                Application.DisplayAlerts = True
            End If
        Next sht
    
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets(sname).Copy After:=Workbooks("SCL Duties.xlsm").Sheets(pname)
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets(sname).Delete
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
        
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you ipStack for the edit - much appreciated

Comment: I don't think it's clear what you are asking. Perhaps read [mcve].

Comment: There are two different tests for sheet names with outcomes dependant on whether they exist or not. I can only seem to get one of the tests to run without getting either an error on either the second "For Each sht In Workbooks("SCL Duties.xlsm").Worksheets"  or an error on the second "If sht.Name = delname Then". I can't get both "If sht.Name = X Then" tests to work.

Comment: When it gets to "If sht.Name = delname Then" I get and error. Hovering over the "If Sh.Name" part gives Automation error, but hovering over the delname gives the correct variable.

Answer (score 0):

I found that I needed to define two different objects as Worksheets, then I could make two separate searches through the workbook.

```
Dim sht As Worksheet
```

And

```
Dim shta As Worksheet
```

Then I could do two searches using

```
For Each sht In Workbooks("SCL Duties.xlsm").Worksheets
```

And

```
For Each shta In Workbooks("SCL Duties.xlsm").Worksheets
```